# Is there a live streaming of the WCC2018 of the players themselves?

Tags: world-championship

I was able to find on YouTube several live streaming videos of GMs commenting the Carlsen-Caruana games. But I wanted to see the actual players and the real board! Is there any streaming of that? I mean, there must be at least one camera on the guys themselves. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure the official website (https://worldchess.com/) has it, which you'll need to pay.

Please note video of the players are copyright owned by World Chess. The games have no copyright but the video of the match is absolutely covered. YouTube users are not in a position to show you anything unless authorized.

It's like finding live World Cup soccer match on YouTube. It didn't happen, and won't happen to chess as well.

Comment: Oh! Makes total sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: "It's like finding live World Cup soccer match on YouTube. It didn't happen..." It did happen.